# Is there an efficient way to generate a symmetric random matrix?

Tags: python, numpy, matrix, random

Is there an efficient way (using numpy) to generate a symmetric random matrix with entries uniformly distributed in [0,1)?

Comment: A common way of creating a symmetric matrix is to add a matrix to its transpose.  `(A+A.T)/2` should stay with in the (0,1) range.  But I can't offhand say whether it is still uniform (I'm mainly worried about the diagonal values).

Comment: @hpaulj it's the other way round diagonal is no prob since you adding twice the same random number, i.e. scale by a factor of two. Off-diagonal you get the sum of two independent uniforms which is not uniform.

Comment: @hpaulj, the off the diagonal elements would be the mean of two uniform variates, so they would have a triangular distribution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a method using `scipy.spatial.distance.squareform`:

`squareform` switches back and forth between the full and "compressed" forms of a symmetric matrix:

```
>>> full = squareform(np.arange(1,11))
>>> full
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3,  4],
       [ 1,  0,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 2,  5,  0,  8,  9],
       [ 3,  6,  8,  0, 10],
       [ 4,  7,  9, 10,  0]])
>>> squareform(full)
array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])
```

As it was designed with distance matrices in mind it leaves the diagonal at zero, so we have to manually fill that in. For that we use `einsum` which used the way we do returns a writable view of the diagonal,

```
>>> from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform
>>> 
>>> N = 5
>>> a = squareform(np.random.random(N*(N-1)//2))
>>> np.einsum('ii->i', a)[:] = np.random.random(N)
>>> a
array([[0.29946651, 0.3636706 , 0.00708741, 0.87536594, 0.62197293],
       [0.3636706 , 0.31774527, 0.05597852, 0.10800514, 0.99871399],
       [0.00708741, 0.05597852, 0.83912235, 0.86241008, 0.01806965],
       [0.87536594, 0.10800514, 0.86241008, 0.11039534, 0.64213608],
       [0.62197293, 0.99871399, 0.01806965, 0.64213608, 0.84755054]])
```

Comment: This method is faster than my answer by not drawing as many random numbers and using assignment over floating point operations.

Answer (score 5):

Let U be a square matrix of uniformly distributed random numbers. You can then add the lower triangular part of U with itself transposed (including the diagonal only once) to get a symmetric matrix with random numbers from the same distribution as U.

```
import numpy as np 

U = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1.0, size=(1000, 1000))
S = np.tril(U) + np.tril(U, -1).T

print(np.histogram(S.flatten()))
print(np.histogram(S[0,:]))
print(np.histogram(S[:,0]))
```

The matrix as a whole as well as any row or column will be uniformly distributed in [0,1) by the documentation for [np.random.uniform](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.random.uniform.html)

Speed-wise I get

```
%timeit U = np.random.uniform(low=0, high=1.0, size=(1000, 1000))
10.6 ms ± 46.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)

%timeit S = np.tril(U) + np.tril(U, -1).T
5.76 ms ± 75.2 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

As other people have noted, you can also do

```
S = (U + U.T) / 2
```

to get symmetry but this will give you triangular distributed random numbers in the off-diagonal since you are summing two uniform random variables.

Comment: _"...but this will give you normally distributed random numbers since you are adding two random variables."_ that would be a marvelously cheap way of generating normal samples ...